# How to filter an object array of another object array in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I know how to filter `bookings` by `b.building.id` here:

```
bookings.filter(b => b.building.id == this.filter.buildingId);
```

But how to filter the `bookings` object array if the `b.modules` is a also an array. Here's my failed attempt:

```
bookings.filter(b => b.modules.programme.facultyId == this.filter.facultyId);
```

And another failed attempt:

```
bookings.filter(b => {
  for (let module of b.modules) {
    module.programme.facultyId == this.filter.facultyId;
  }
});
```

**Update:**

Here's an example of `bookings` result in JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "semesterId": 1,
    "room": {
        "capacity": 17,
        "code": null,
        "building": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Faculty of Science"
        },
        "id": 15,
        "name": "FSB 1.10"
    },
    "building": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Faculty of Science"
    },
    "bookDate": "2020-11-10T00:00:00",
    "timeSlots": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "startTime": "1900-01-01T07:50:00",
            "endTime": "1900-01-01T08:40:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "startTime": "1900-01-01T08:50:00",
            "endTime": "1900-01-01T09:40:00"
        }
    ],
    "modules": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Computer Systems and Information Technology",
            "code": "SS-1202",
            "lecturers": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "Lim",
                    "title": "Dr."
                }
             ],
            "programme": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Computer Science",
                "shortName": null,
                "facultyId": 1
            }
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bookings.filter(b => b.modules.filter(module => module.programme.facultyId == this.filter.facultyId));
```

and if module.programme.facultyId is unique you can use:

```
bookings.filter(b => b.modules.find(module => module.programme.facultyId == this.filter.facultyId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

There are two things might be missing, first second `filter is not returning` after the filter and in some cases it may miss the **`this`** reference.

```
const that = this;

bookings.filter(b => {
  return b.modules.filter(module.programme.facultyId == that.filter.facultyId)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax:

```
var result = bookings.filter(b => b.modules.filter(m => m.programme.facultyId === b.facultyId));
```